Zendesk widget not showing up
we are integrating Zendesk widget into a website. We are using enterprise version.
We have Dev, qa, Stage and prod environments.
The widget uses authentication, and is successfully working (showing up) in dev and qa. There is not difference between the envs except the URL.
The Zendesk authentication on staging is returning an error we cannot find any examples of:
{"error":"Bad request","message":"Invalid message(s): * Could not be verified"}
Just understanding what this error be related to, could help us figure it out. Thanks for your help

I had the same problem. Zendesk Support advised to re-generate the secret with which you sign the JWT and it helped in my case.
Apart from that, I would advise you to check the correctness of JWT generation in general. Maybe the secret is getting double encoded or iat is not in seconds.
However, first I would try to regenerate the shared secret.
